# Netty forked tomcat - supported Netty version

Tags: openssl, netty

I was working to get my Netty working for Openssl support and I encounter these two errors

```
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4828 - UnsupportedOperationException when Unsafe not available
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4918 - io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000103:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: IMHO these are development questions. I have faced it while trying to run Netty with Openssl. I faced one of the Exceptions stated above when I was running 4.0.26.Final version and the other exception when moved to 4.0.35.Final. And finally it got resolved when I moved to 4.0.36.Final. I put it here as an answered question in case someone looks for it. In any case, if the moderators feel that this is not a question that meets the criteria I will take it away. But this is not a Dev Ops or system question.

Answer (score 1):

4.0.36.Final has the fix and works well with netty-tcnative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070954/netty-latency-goes-up-with-forked-tomcat-netty